# How to test the components used NGRX?

Tags: angular, testing, karma-runner, ngrx

I need to check that the button call the dispatch after click.
is it  a true way?

```
 it('should remove dispatch on click', async(() => {
const hds = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(ngrx.Store);
const saveSpy = spyOn(hds, 'dispatch');

click(page.removeGeospatialBtn);

expect(saveSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1);}));
```

and wondering how the fakeStore should look. the best I could come up with

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports:   [
    GeneralModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/'},
    {provide: ngrx.Store, useClass: class {
      dispatch(action: Action) {

      }
    }},
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```